# jQuery - preventDefault() in .each function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use preventDefault() in .each function for collection of buttons and its not working. When I use it with one .click function it works fine but inside .each is not

Whan am I doing wrong?

Here is my .js code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var findingStatus = $('#findingStatus').attr('finding-status-type');
    var findingLike = $('#finding_like_btn');
    var findingDislikeBox = $('.finding_dislike_add');
    var findingDislikeCollection = $('.finding_dislike_add_btn')
    var findingUnlike = $('#finding_unlike_btn');
    var findingDislikeRemoved = $('#finding_dislike_removed');

    var alertBox = $('.alert-box').hide();



    if (findingStatus == 0) {
        findingDislikeBox.show();
        findingUnlike.hide();
        findingDislikeRemoved.hide();
    }
    else if (findingStatus == 1) {
        findingDislikeBox.hide();
        findingUnlike.show();
        findingDislikeRemoved.hide();
    } 
    else if (findingStatus == 2) {
        findingDislikeRemoved.show();
        findingUnlike.show();
        findingDislikeBox.hide();
        findingLike.hide();

    }

    findingDislikeCollection.each(function() {



        var findingDislike = $(this).clone();
        var url = findingDislike.attr("href");

        findingDislike.click(function(event) {

            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {

                    if (data.profileState == 1) {

                        $('#dislike_count_btn').text('Odrzuć' + data.DislikeCount);
                        findingDislikeBox.hide();
                        findingDislikeRemoved.show();
                        findingUnlike.show();
                        //findingUnDislike.show();
                        //findingUnDislike.attr('disabled', false );
                        //findingUnDislike.text('Cofnij');
                    }
                    else {
                        alertBox.show();
                        if ($('.alert-box-msg').length==0) {
                            $('.alert-area').prepend('<p class="alert-area alert-box-msg">Żeby korzystać z tej funkcji musisz być zalogowany.</p>');

                        }
                        findingDislike.attr('disabled', false );
                    }

                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Problem z serwerem, spróbuj ponownie za kilka minut.');
                    findingDislike.attr('disabled', false );
                }

            });


        });



    });



    $('html').click(function (e) {
        if (!$(e.target).hasClass('alert-area')) {
            $('.alert-box').hide();
            findingDislike.attr('disabled', false );
        }
    });


});
```

Thanks for answer

Comment: Question 1: Why is it that you are creating a clone of the node and attaching event to the clone?

Comment: This code will obviously not work. The element that you cloned is not in the DOM. Hence the click cannot happen on the clone.. Hence the code never executes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are cloning the element with [`.clone`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) which means you're not actually attaching an event listener to anything in the DOM. Cloned elements must be manually inserted into the DOM with JavaScript for them to have any effect.

Comment: I removed .clone() and preventDefault() works fine, but ajax not, console.log(url) says that is undefined
I have got now: var findingDislike = $(this);

Comment: So is `findingDislike.attr("href")` returning undefined?

Comment: yes, i ve got:
var findingDislike = $(this);
var url = findingDislike.attr("href");

and console gives url - undefined

Comment: problem solved, rookie mistake: I used "li" not an "a" object thats why arrt('href') didnt worked, anyway thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a correct way. Following should work:

```
findingDislikeCollection.click(function(event){
  var findingDislike = $(this);
  var url = findingDislike.attr("href");
  //AJAX call
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

More details on click event are given here:
https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: Thanks for answer Hiral, I am rookie in jQuery

I have to use .each function bacause I have many buttons, I ve tried to do like this
var findingDislike = $(this); insted of .clone() , now preventDefault() work but ajax not, I gives undefined in url :/